# How do I get pandoc to generate book parts?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I'm using markdown to write a book with pandoc. Pandoc can generate headings using `#`, `##` and so on, but I also want book parts (equivalent to `\part` in LaTeX). I tried using `#-` (a markup that some sites such as Leanpub use) but it doesn't work. So, how can I generate book parts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [the `raw_tex` extension](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-raw_tex), you can simply add `\part` wherever you want it, e.g.:

```
\part{Part I}
# Heading
Blah
```

Add `+raw_tex` to the input format when you run Pandoc to enable it:

```
pandoc --from markdown+raw_tex --to pdf -o book.pdf *.md
```

Answer (score 4):

The intended way is to use `#` headings for parts and to use the option [`--top-level-division=part`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--top-level-division):

> Treat top-level headings as the given division type in LaTeX, ConTeXt,
> DocBook, and TEI output. The hierarchy order is part, chapter, then section;
> all headings are shifted such that the top-level heading becomes the
> specified type.

Your Markdown should look like this:

```
# Part heading

## Chapter heading

### Section heading

#### Subsection heading
```

and so on.